# Unrecognised Json object

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I am creating simple app where user clicks on a button and JSON object is returned from the database. The structure of object is shown bellow. However, the object is not recognized and the execution is failing. Any ideas why it is happening?

Response array from PHP passed to js

```
array(2) (
  [success] => (bool) true
  [cnt] => array(2) (
    [2014-11-28] => array(2) (
      [visits] => (string) 1115
      [searches] => null
    )
    [2014-11-29] => array(2) (
      [visits] => (string) 493
      [searches] => 0
    )

    )
)
```

JSON object

```
{
   "success":true,
   "cnt":{
      "2014-11-28":{
         "visits":"1115",
         "searches":null
      },
      "2014-11-29":{
         "visits":"493",
         "searches":0
      }
   }
}
```

function which is parsing the object

```
 $.post(JOBK.ajaxurl, data, function (resp) {
            if (resp.success) {

                // Append rows    
                $.each(resp.cnt, function (dateCol) {
                    $.each(dateCol, function (visitsCol, searchesCol) {
                        // Insert a row in the table at row index 0
                        var newRow = tableRef.insertRow(tableRef.rows.length);

                    });
                });
            }

        }, 'json');
    });
```

Comment: If you `console.log(resp);` before your if statement, what is the result?

Comment: What do you mean by "the object isn't recognized"? It would be easier to help if you posted the actual data you're returning.

Comment: The object "to be parsed" is *not* JSON. You're going to have to show us what your server is actually outputting.

Comment: The actual data is the one it shown above. which needs to be parsed by the function.
@meagar I guess that the object is not well formatted?

Comment: No, it's not valid JSON at all. It's not anything remotely like JSON.

Comment: I;ve updated the question with JSON object coming from console

Comment: What do you mean by "the object isn't recognized"?

Comment: I mean that the function is not excecuting the line : if (resp.success) at all,

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to return valid json string

```
{"success": true, "cnt": {"2014-11-28": {"visits": "1115", "searches": null}, "2014-11-29": {"visits": "493", "searches": 0}}}
```

Also I think you not need second loop, just one =>

```
// Append rows    
$.each(resp.cnt, function (dateCol, date) {
   var visits = dateCol.visits;
   var searches = dateCol.visits;
   //... do anything with it here
});
```